# Storing UIImage in Core Data with the new External Storage flag

Tags: iphone, image, core-data, ios5

I know that the storing of UIImage's in core data has been discussed a lot, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573072/coredata-store-images-to-db-or-not/2573113#2573113), but that was pre-ios5. Now that we have the external storage flag, do you guys think it would be a fine idea to store UIImage's directly in the entity, as a separate entity, or still on the disk?

[Here](http://bluecrowbar.com/blog/2011/08/coredata-external.html) is a source explaining the external storage option.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Core Data Release Notes for iOS 5.0](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html)

> When enabled, Core Data heuristically decides on a per-value basis if
>   it should save the data directly in the database or store a URI to a
>   separate file which it manages for you. You cannot query based on the
>   contents of a binary data property if you use this option.

And from your link [External Binary Data](http://bluecrowbar.com/blog/2011/08/coredata-external.html), the heuristic seems to be

> Objects that are smaller than 1MB are stored in the database. For
>   objects that are larger, an external file is created and the database
>   just stores a reference to it.

So the following advice is still valid: [CoreData : store images to DB or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573072/coredata-store-images-to-db-or-not/2573113#2573113)

> - < 100kb store in the same table as the relevant data
> - < 1mb store in a separate table attached via a relationship to avoid loading unnecessarily
> - > 1mb store on disk and reference it inside of Core Data

The flag sets Core Data to follow that advice and automatically store images >1MB as a separate disk file.

Comment: So in that case we should probably put it in a separate entity in case it's in the 100kb-1mb range since the external storage doesn't account for that case?

Comment: Caveat: there is a bug with external image storage that makes it crash when deleted, sometimes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930427/error-uiimage-deleteexternalreferencefrompermanentlocation-unrecognized-se

Comment: There is another bug with external storage and migration. If you try to create a new model and then use lightweight migration then you lose all the 'Binary Data' that are stored on an external file.

Comment: @zirinisp Any workarounds?? Im having that issue with an app, i have it live on the appstore and users stored images like that and i need to migrate. Can i use manual migration?

Comment: can we access that url that is referenced for uploading image to other services?