# UIImage CompressionQuality not Linear

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uiimage, compression

I would like to save a UIImage to a CoreData Entity.

Per [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924840/storing-uiimage-in-core-data-with-the-new-external-storage-flag), in order to save this UIImage to the same Entity Table, suggested size of UIImage should be < 100kb

Thus when user takes a UIImage from a UIImagePickerController (either library or camera),   I would like to do a `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` @ `CompressionQuality` rate that would render this UIImage data < 100kb

Playing around with

```
let imgData: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(CameraImage, <#compressionQuality: CGFloat#>)
let size = imgData.length
```

I've realized that 0.8 is not equivalent to 80% Data size of 1.0 compression.

---

**How could I take any UIImage of any size and compress it down to data:** with a size of **100kb maximum**, so that as much integrity is held while allowing the size to be **small enough to store in CoreData Entity?**

NOTE: my original idea was to test `size` of UIImage then compress it @ "rate X = 100,000/size"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to downsize your image to be under 100kb, all you have to do is create a Coredata attribute of type binary and tick the "Allows External Storage" box. Coredata will take care of the rest for you:

1. Create an attribute named `imageData` of type binary and allowing for external storage
2. Create a transient attribute named 'image' and implement custom getters and setters as per below:

Files larger than 1MB will be stored on a separate folder relative to your database folder whereas smaller files are saved directly to the sqlite file.

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
    if (data) {
        [self setImageData:data];
    }
}

- (UIImage*)image
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.imageData];
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Ok but I have a TableView which shows all CoreData entities `Person` and displays each entry's image(possibly 200+ images)...which unless these images are compressed could crash the App, No?

Comment: In that case you should also create a thumbnail size version of your image to display in the tableview. This is not strictly necessary as if you do things correctly only the cells being displayed will have the images loaded (i.e. you may have 5-10 images shown on screen at any given time and when the user scrolls an image is unloaded while a new one is loaded).