# Limitations of Saving into Core Data iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data, swift2

First apologies if this is not a suitable question. But it seems like a good place to ask.

Theoretically speaking, is their a limit to the amount of data that can be & should be stored/saved within core data of an App.Would saving large amount of data, such as text, images etc within core data damage the app in any way or cause issues to its performance.

I am creating an App where users can search items from an external API. If the users likes an item they can store them into their personal "favourites item list". I want save that favourites list data as core data. Keeping in mind that the list could grow fast, depends on the users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With core data, you're only really limited by disk space.

Comment: Also if you haven't yet saved your data - you're then limited by available RAM.

Comment: @Phoen1xUK By disk space you mean, iPhone storage? If so, is it a good programming practice, saving large data into Core Data in your professional opinion.

Comment: @Phoen1xUK Currently every time the user tries to access the "Favourites list" a HTTP call is made to get the data. Which is a slow process & I want the user to have access to this list while not connected to the internet.

Comment: Yea, the amount of space you have to make use of (e.g. some iPhones are 32gb, 64gb etc.). By large data, do you mean large amounts of data? Or individual pieces of data that are in themselves large

Comment: Well its not really a right or wrong answer as it depends on what you're doing. For example, a favourites list of websites is probably better if the websites are not downloaded since they are things that can change and be updated often.

Comment: @Phoen1xUK large amount of data. By data I specifically mean "The name of the item ( i.e a String ) & "The image of the item". If a  user has 100 items saved in the list then each item would have these two things. The String itself would take very little disk space and the image might take a bit more.

Comment: If that's the purpose of the app then I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Also [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573072/coredata-store-images-to-db-or-not/2573113#2573113)

Comment: @Phoen1xUK This is very helpful. Thank you so much!